# Which controller is used when bulk printing invoices? (Magento1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, massaction

On the orders grid, when using the Action `Print Invoices`, which controller is used to generate the invoices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see by the source code that the called path is *admin/sales_invoice/pdfinvoices*. 
So you can look for a `pdfinvoicesAction` function inside the code: you will find two, one for each of this files:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

For the admin router, the file you're looking for (`admin/sales_invoice`) is: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/InvoiceController.php, that extends the first file.

Comment: +1 for the logic of how you found it. I actually asked the wrong question I think but you helped me find what I need, which is the the pdfinvoicesAction() function in invoice.php